# How to fix issue with hard disk leading to "The installer encountered an unrecoverable error" with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, hardware-failure, asus-laptop, hard-drive-recovery

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on an Asus having an SSD (1To) as the only hard disk and I ran into a bunch of issues.

When I thought that the installation ended I got this error message displayed: "We're sorry, the installer crashed. After you close this window, we'll allow you to file a bug report using the integrated bug reporting tool. This will gather the information about your system and your installation process. The details will be sent to our bug tracker and a developer will attend to the problem as soon as possible." The error message window had the title: "Installer crashed"

Then another error message got displayed: "The system log from your installation contains an error. The specific error commonly occurs when there is an issue with the disk to which you are trying to install Ubuntu. It is recommended that you back up important data on your disk and investigate the situation. Measures you might take include checking cable connections for your disk and using software tools to investigate the health of your hardware." The error message window had no title.

The last error message was: "The installer encountered an unrecoverable error. A desktop session will now be run so that you may investigate the problem or try installing again." The error was under the title "Installation failed."

About the computer:

Name: Zenbook Edition 30 UX334

Constructor: Asus

Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-8565U Processor 1.8 GHz (8M Cache, up to 4.6 GHz, 4 cores)

Graphics: Intel® UHD Graphics 620, NVIDIA® GeForce® MX250, 2GB GDDR5

Storage: 1TB M.2 NVMe™ PCIe® 3.0 Performance SSD

Memory: 16GB LPDDR3 on board, Memory Max Up to:16GB

I bought it about 2 years ago and it came with Windows 10, after 5-6 months it started crashing (blue window out of the blue...) and rebooting continuously. Since I had the warranty available I took it to an Azure store and they fixed it. On the "bill" it was written that they replaced the hard disk. And it worked well again. After roughly a year or so it had the same issue again. I thought it was because an update of Windows 10 because when I restored to a previous version it started to work well again, but the same issue happened (blue window, rebooting endlessly). That's why I tried to switch to Ubuntu.

I'd like to ask you what I can do to try figuring out what's happening with this laptop and how to fix it. The second error message suggested to check disk cable connections but I have no idea how to do it and I'm afraid I'd mess it up if I follow some random youtube tutorial so I'd be happy if someone provided with links they trust. Also, I don't know what software I can use to figure out what's happening with the hard disk and how to "use" this software since I can install no OS on the laptop.

Thank you all for any help ^^

P.S.: I don't have a way to get a live USB with the latest version of Ubuntu but I suppose the issue with my hardware and not the software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue is **hardware**, i.e., the M.2 NVMe™ PCIe® 3.0 Performance SSD, that needs to be fixed before installing Ubuntu. Some [Windows 10 updates have been known to damage the SSD](https://www.tomsguide.com/news/windows-10-update-could-kill-your-ssd-what-you-need-to-know), so that could be the cause of your issue.

A simple way to diagnose that is to **run from a USB drive**, rather than from the SSD -- if that works, then almost certainly the issue is a dying SSD. You state, "I don't have a way to get a live USB with the latest version of Ubuntu,", but if you have Ubuntu v. 20.04 LTS,that should work well for this test. Do **not** select *install*, but pick the default, *Try Ubuntu*, running entirely from the USB and RAM.

If the SSD is the cause, a replacement would be over US$100. Since you've already established that there was an issue during the original warranty, go back to store with a copy of the repair order. Even though the *original* warranty might have expired, the replacement part should be covered *at least from the time you received it.* Many countries and states enforce an extended warranty on repair parts, and a reputable manufacturer would want to stand behind their products.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the "Try Ubuntu" with the USB and it works fine. I haven't used it for complex things, I just tried browsing and going through different files. Thank you for your advice on the warranty, it's very helpful. I never knew that! I have tried to vote your question but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation, but it's taken into consideration ^^

Comment: @KindNewbie, glad it helped... and I hope the dealer or Asus honor their obligation to provide a machine that works longer than a few months.